# CakePHP - Creating a link URL without the anchor tag

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePHP and want to create a URL to a controller/view without including the anchor tag.

In other words if I use

```
$this->Html->link('foo',array('controller'=>'bar','action'=>'display'));
```

Then the output is a formatted link that can be displayed... but I just want the URL without the HTML around it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'bar', 'action' => 'display'));
```

With optional second parameter to make it a full URL including `http://` and so on:

```
echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'bar', 'action' => 'display'), true);
```

Answer (score 2):

I just needed the same thing, but it changed on Cake 3.
Now we have to use:

```
echo $this->Url->build(["controller" => "bar", "action" => "display","bar"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need URL:

```
echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'bar','action'=>'display'));
```